# PHP and MySQL: Inserting selects wrong $row

Tags: php, mysql

I am needing help with my small script.
You see, when I press `$_POST['accept_req']` it doesn't select the `$req_user` I want (`$row['username']`). It either selects the row above or the row below it, I have no idea what to do.

```
$requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `party_requests` WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($requests, MYSQL_ASSOC)){   

    $req_user = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);

    if(isset($_POST['accept_req'])){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO party_members (`party_id`, `username`) VALUES ('".$get_party_id."', '".$req_user."')") or die("Could not be completed.");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM party_requests WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id' AND username = '$req_user' ");
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }

    echo "<p>", $req_user, "<form action='' method='post'>", "<input type='submit' name='accept_req' value='Accept'/>", "</form>" ,"</p>";

}
```

I am aware that `mysql_*` is deprecated, please ignore that.

Comment: What `$req_username` ? it's not in your code.

Comment: You don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` for values retrieved from the database. That should already be safe.

Comment: Your `$result` is basicly `mysql_query(mysql_query(....));`

Comment: I am confused what `$_POST['req_accept']` is when you should have `$_POST['accept_req']`... which is it? Your submit button has `name='accept_req'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is supposed to be `$req_user` sorry, 

$req_user = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);

Comment: Try putting `if(isset($_POST['accept_req']))` on top of `$requests = mysql_query` as already stated in an answer below. Seems to be the most likely reason.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I need it inside the `while` so that I can define `$req_user` as `$row['username']`

Comment: Since your submit button is named `accept_req` it won't execute anything above that. It will only execute below it, IF `isset` ;-) so anything above that will be ignored as soon as you click the submit button. Plain & simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
$requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `party_requests` WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($requests, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
    $req_user =$row['username'];
}

if(isset($_POST['accept_req']) and isset($req_user))
 {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO party_members (`party_id`, `username`) VALUES ('".$get_party_id."', '".$req_user."')") or die("Could not be completed.");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM party_requests WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id' AND username = '$req_user' ");
    header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
   }

echo "<p>", $req_user, "<form action='' method='post'>", "<input type='submit' name='accept_req' value='Accept'/>", "</form>" ,"</p>";
```

or this way :

```
 if(isset($_POST['accept_req']))
 {
   $requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `party_requests` WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id'");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($requests, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {   
       $req_user =$row['username'];
   }

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO party_members (`party_id`, `username`) VALUES ('".$get_party_id."', '".$req_user."')") or die("Could not be completed.");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM party_requests WHERE party_id = '$get_party_id' AND username = '$req_user' ");
    header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
 }

   if(mysql_num_rows($requests)){  //If there isn't any results it outputs "No requests"
echo "<p>", $req_user, "<form action='' method='post'>", "<input type='submit' name='accept_req' value='Accept'/>", "</form>" ,"</p>";
}else{
    echo "No requests";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The select statement is outside the

```
if(isset($_POST['accept_req'])){...}
```

so the code is retrieving the wrong id. You need to put it inside the if statement if i'm understanding what you are trying to do